# In Django Rest, how can one specify a model as a field for another model?

Tags: python, django, rest, serialization

This explanation may be a bit long, so please bear with me I'll attempt to explain my problem first, and then explain what I've tried at the end. I'd like to serialize a model over the API as a field of another model, with only a subset of the first model's fields. (**Edit**: I'm also aware of setting the resursive depth of a model in a serializer for `ForeignKey`s, but as far as I'm aware, you can't omit certain field of the linked model, or specify it to recurse on some only some fields) I have two models, one which has a `ForeignKey` to the other as follows

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField()
    modelb_ref = models.ForeignKey(ModelB)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField()
    field1 = models.TextField()
    field2 = models.TextField()
    field3 = models.TextField()
    field4 = models.TextField()
    field5 = models.TextField()
    field6 = models.TextField()
    field7 = models.TextField()
    field8 = models.TextField()
```

For these models, I'd like to have the API show as follows:

`http://site/api/v1/ModelA`

```
[
    {
        "id": 1
        "name": "Model A Name"
        "description": "Test of Model A"
        "modelb_ref": [
            "id": 1
            "name": "Model B"
            "description" : "Model B's description"
    }
]
```

So as you can see, the foreign key link to Model B only shows the name and description, and not any of field 1, 2, 3, 4

Now, what I've tried is creating a model serializer of ModelB which looks like:

```
class ModelBSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelB
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description')
```

And a model serializer of ModelA which looks like:

```
class ModelASerializer(serialziers.ModelSerializer):
    modelb_ref = ModelBSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'modelb_ref')
```

And this works 100%, so long as `ModelBSerializer` is defined before `ModelASerializer`, however, because of other reasons, and how a vareity of mdoels are linked, doing this is not an option, it needs to work even if `ModelASerializer` is defined first (and as far as I know, you can't forward declare in Python)/

#### At this point I'll go over a few other things I tried to circumvent the issue, if you don't care to read this, and already know the solution, please ignore this.

I then attempted to get around `ModelSerializerB` not be defined by placing the call inside a function, as that has worked before in other, non django related activities, which gave:

```
class ModelASerializer(serialziers.ModelSerializer):
    modelb_ref = get_modelb_ref()

    get_modelb_ref(self):
        return ModelBSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'modelb_ref')
```

However, this gives the problem of `get_modelb_ref` not yet being declared, so, with what little knowledge I have of Rest, I attempted to make it a `SerializerMethodField`

```
class ModelASerializer(serialziers.ModelSerializer):
    modelb_ref = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    get_modelb_ref(self, obj):
        return ModelBSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'modelb_ref')
```

However, from what I can tell, this attempts to pass the model itself, and not the model instance that I need.

Thanks for taking the time to read, and if you can provide any help, and point out any other mistakes or bad practices I have, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Not sure if this is possible given your dependency constraints, but you should consider breaking `ModelBSerializer` to 2 classes: a basic one (sufficient for the API) and a full one (inheriting from the basic one). You can place the basic one above `ModelASerializer` and the inherited one below (if the dependencies allow you to).

Comment: Unless another solution can be found, I think that's probably the option that I'll go with, thank you for the suggestion!